# i want to add numbering at the beginning of the name in the dropdown list in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

in my controller i have written like this

```
@agendas = @agendas.each{ |e| puts e.name }
      @agenda_alpha = @agendas.each_with_index.map { |agenda_key, i| ["#{i+1}.#{agenda_key}"] }
```

in my slim file i wrote this

```
label_method: ->(agenda) { @agenda_alpha },
```

This are the attributes in my rails console

i have to fetch the name attribute into the dropdown

Comment: Can you edit your question to specify what kind of views you are using? Are trying to do this in an erb template? Do you have an array containing the strings 'Apple', 'Ball', 'Cat'? And existing code to make the drop-down from that?

Comment: i am using html.slim files for the views i have the array already loaded in a variable

Answer (score 3):

It probably makes sense to translate the options into the required format in the controller or a helper first.

```
@options = %w[Apple Ball Cat]
@options = @options.each_with_index.map { |value, i| ["#{i}.#{value}", value] }
#=> [["0.Apple", "Apple"], ["1.Ball", "Ball"], ["2.Cat", "Cat"]]
```

Then just use this `@options` in your view:

```
f.select(:attribute_name, @options)
```